# No route to host error when trying to login in a public wifi hotspot

Tags: networking, wireless

I'm using Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS, kernel version 4.15.0-47-generic.
In the office we have a public wifi hotspot. However, when I connect, I have to accept some terms and conditions before I can use the internet. This does not work on Ubuntu though, I get an "No route to host" error message for this page.

- It works when I reboot and accept the terms and conditions in Windows, then reboot again to Ubuntu. I can directly connect.
- For other wifi hotspots (at the airport or hotels) I don't have this problem. So this only occurs for this one wifi hotspot.
- I've already checked the URL for the login page I get forwarded to, which is correct.
- I've tried setting DNS servers manually in `nm-connection-editor` (using the DNS hosts that are used on my Windows machine for this hotspot), without success
- I've tried `sudo dpkg-reconfigure resolvconf`, without success

What can I do to find and fix the issue such that I can login and connect on this wifi hotspot as well?

Comment: Top tip for any public wifi: Use http://neverssl.com to login, because most websites are https these days, and many public wifi can't handle that.

Answer (score 9):

Finally, I found the issue. The problem was the docker daemon creating network bridges that claimed the subnetwork `172.16.0.0`, `172.17.0.0`, ... and the wifi-hotspot-service I needed to connect to had an IP that was in one of the above subnetworks.

What helped me:

- Remove the docker containers I didn't need anymore
- Run `sudo docker network prune` to delete unused docker networks
- Change the default docker0 bridge IP address (in my case docker was installed via snap, i.e. add `"bip": "192.168.154.1/24",` to the file `/var/snap/docker/current/config/daemon.json`)
- Restart docker-daemon (or your system)

Comment: sudo docker network prune was all I needed

Comment: See: https://askubuntu.com/a/1136333/978690 I got some problems with a VSCode devcontainer, so I ended up doing `docker system prune`, which also removed dangling containers.

Comment: thanks a million. I can't believe its working.

Comment: Your answer gave the underlying cause, but I couldn't find a way to remove `docker0` interface until I read this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/50036874/167745

Comment: To restart dockerd you can do `sudo systemctl restart docker`, as per https://stackoverflow.com/a/75913981/9778755